# MD5 vs GPG signature

Tags: md5, gnupg

According sites like [apache](http://www.apache.org/dev/release-signing.html) signing a file (generating a checksum) using GPG is more secure than plain old MD5.  I don't understand why most people use MD5 instead.  Can some explain the real differences in plain technical English?

Answer (score 6):

An MD5 checksum can be generated by anyone who has access to a file. An attacker who breaks into a site, or executes a man-in-the-middle attack, can easily change the MD5 checksum so it matches the compromised file.

A GPG signature, on the other hand, can (in theory) only be generated by the owner of the corresponding private key. If the signer is in your web of trust, the signature verifies the integrity of the file contents *and* demonstrates that the key owner vouches for the file contents.

Also, MD5 has begun to show some weaknesses in the last several years; GPG tends to use more up-to-date algorithms.

Probably MD5 checksums are still commonly used because they're easier. (SHA-1 is better than MD5, and is becoming more common.)

UPDATE (4 years later): MD5 should now be considered insecure, and distinct files with identical SHA-1 checksums have been demonstrated. There are better checksum algorithms, but I won't recommend a specific one; I suspect this answer will still be here after they've been broken.

Comment: hmm...I think its time we all switch to gpg

Comment: @LogicalConfusion: GPG and MD5 have different purposes. MD5 is just a fingerprint for a given file, and sometime that's all you need. A GPG/PGP signature has to be made by the owner of a particular key -- and it can't be verified unless you have access to that public key. That's not too bad if the public key is on the public servers, but it's extra overhead that you don't always need. MD5 is known to be somewhat week; SHA1 is better, and newer algorithms are better yet.

Comment: For example, Git uses SHA1 checksums to identify content; there would be no particular advantage in having it use GPG/PGP instead. And you can always PGP-sign a file containing SHA1 (or SHA-whatever) checksums. (In fact Git supports GPG signing of tags.)

Comment: Excellent observation Keith. Generating a pgp+sha1 "figer-print" for a file is definitely more secure than plain old MD5 checksums.  Its rumoured that a scientist already managed to compromise it according to wiki.  I don't see why distrowatch.com doesn't use gpg keys for their iso files. YOu even admitted that its pretty trivial to break MD5. Lets see the admins over at distrowatch have to say....